# Typehint importing module dynamically using importlib

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-importlib

Give something as follows:

```py
import importlib

module_path = "mod"
mod = importlib.import_module(module_path, package=None)
print(mod.Foo.Bar.x)
```

where `mod.py` is:

```py
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        x = 1
```

`mypy file.py --strict` [raises the following error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=67cc868bafb54332190a4a74981375f3):

```
file.py:7: error: Module has no attribute "Foo"  [attr-defined]
```

I'm wondering how one is supposed to go about type-hinting this, or if this is something which would typically just be ignored with `# type: ignore[attr-defined]` *(assuming that the code is necessary, and the only options are type-hinting or ignoring the type-hint)*?

---

##### Why I am using `importlib` in this situation

The way that `importlib` is being used is that there's some path:

```
x.y.<changes>.z
```

Where `<changes>` is dynamic, but the others are fixed. I'm confident that the module will contain the attributes which are being called, but due to `<changes>`, `importlib` is used for the import.

Which might be summarised as:

> *I do not know precisely which module I will be importing, but I know it will have a class `Foo` in it*.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using importlib in this situation? Is it a case of "I do not know which module I will be importing, and which classes it will have"? Is it a case of "I do not know precisely which module I will be importing, but I know it will have a class Foo in it"? Is it a case of "I know exactly which module I will be importing, I just don't know where it will be found"? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: ``importlib`` can import *arbitrary* code – a type checker has no way of knowing what module it provides. The only option is to structurally type the entire module and hint ``mod`` with it, which seems to defeat the point of using ``importlib``.

Comment: @AlexWaygood I've edited the post

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not too sure what it means here to "structurally type the entire module".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was alluded to by @MisterMiyagi [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090545/typehint-importing-module-dynamically-using-importlib?noredirect=1#comment122113259_69090545), I think the solution here is to use structural, rather than nominal, subtyping. *Nominal* subtyping is where we use direct class inheritance to define type relationships. For example, `collections.Counter` is a subtype of `dict` because it directly inherits from `dict`. *Structural* subtyping, however, is where we define types based on certain properties a class has or certain behaviours it displays. `int` is a subtype of `typing.SupportsFloat` not because it directly inherits from `SupportsFloat` (it doesn't), but because `SupportsFloat` is defined as a certain *interface*, and `int` satisfies that interface.

When type-hinting, we can define structural types using `typing.Protocol`. You could satisfy MyPy in this situation like this:

```
import importlib
from typing import cast, Protocol

class BarProto(Protocol):
    x: int
    
class FooProto(Protocol):
    Bar: type[BarProto]
    
class ModProto(Protocol):
    Foo: type[FooProto]

module_path = "mod"
mod = cast(ModProto, importlib.import_module(module_path, package=None))

print(mod.Foo.Bar.x)

reveal_type(mod)
reveal_type(mod.Foo)
reveal_type(mod.Foo.Bar)
reveal_type(mod.Foo.Bar.x)
```

We've defined several interfaces here:

- `BarProto`: in order to satisfy this interface, a type has to have an attribute `x` that's of type `int`.
- `FooProto`: in order to satisfy this interface, a type has to have an attribute `Bar` that is a class of which instances satisfy the `BarProto` protocol.
- `ModProto`: in order to satisfy this interface, a type has to have an attribute `Foo` that is a class of which instances satisfy the `FooProto` protocol.

Then, when importing the module, we use `typing.cast` to assert to the type-checker that the module we're importing satisfies the `ModProto` protocol.

Run it [through MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=c9e0e2b4ffd663e40420cc3fd9755cf3), and it informs us it has inferred the following types:

```
main.py:18: note: Revealed type is "__main__.ModProto"  
main.py:19: note: Revealed type is "Type[__main__.FooProto]"
main.py:20: note: Revealed type is "Type[__main__.BarProto]"
main.py:21: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

Read more about structural subtyping in python [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/).